# What's bad about starting a pyQt thread from a python thread (not main)?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I had a python console script that I wanted to add a basic status window to, so without knowing much about pyqt I added a window. If I started pyqt from my main thread, it blocked everything else, so I started it from another thread instead. It's been running fine like this for months, but I just noticed a warning (not sure how I missed it before):
`WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.` I'm wondering what problems this might cause.

This is a slimmed down version of the code I'm using, just updating the window titlebar:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading
import sys
from time import sleep

class MainWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(statusLine)
        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.timer.start(500, self)


    def updateWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(statusLine)


    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if event.timerId() == self.timer.timerId():
            self.updateWindow()
        else:
            super(MainWidget, self).timerEvent(event)


def startWindow():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWidget()
    mw.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global statusLine
    statusLine = 'foo'
    threadWindow = threading.Thread(target=startWindow)
    threadWindow.start()
    sleep(2)  # process lots of data
    statusLine = 'bar'
    # keep doing stuff and updating statusLine
```

Edit: it looks like I don't get the warning with this simplified sample; instead, I seem to only get it if I start up multiple other python threads before the one that starts pyQt. However the question still stands: what's wrong with doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that since users interact with the GUI there is some danger that people kill the GUI without actually killing the main program, this can lead to:

1. Problems because another instance gets started leading to resource leakage, clashes, etc. &
2. Problems because the `__main__` tries to update the GUI which no longer exists.

It seem to be generally considered best practice in programs with GUIs, whether QT or WX, to have the GUI as the `__main__` and have child threads that do any background, computationally intensive, processing.  Of course it is still a very good idea to explicitly kill any child threads in your OnExit method(s).

Comment: Thanks. So for my case, where I'm bolting on a simple gui as an afterthought, it's not so much that calling pyQt from a thread is going to directly break anything, it's just that it becomes less graceful to manage. For best practice (and if I were to start all over again) I can definitely see doing it differently. For now I've made sure that closing the GUI will also trigger the main thread to gracefully shut down, and main doesn't do anything at all to the gui directly, instead updating global variables (which of course is terrible practice I'm sure) which the gui reads on a timer.

Comment: Rather than bolting on a GUI it is nearly as quick to whip up a front-end/wrapper.

Comment: Hmm that's an idea. But I understand that pyQt uses its own style of threading, so I'm concerned reworking my original multi-threaded code to work under Qt would be a sizable undertaking. Or is there a trick to just plug it into Qt?

Comment: The main "Trick" is separation of user interaction and computation - if you split your user interaction into gather start-up options, reporting of progress, changes to ongoing progress and finishing up and have all of those in a separate UI file then you just need a GUI file that does those bits.  It is worth looking at the pubsub model.

Comment: Ok, for now I'll probably leave it as is as it sounds like it shouldn't cause me any problems (which is mainly what I wanted to find out) but I'll keep this in mind for next time I need to add a UI. Thanks.